React Higher-Order Components, dose not pass props to Wrapped component when Higher-Order Components state changed
console inside MyComponent print value for the first time but value dose not show on view.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const withLoading = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class WithLoading extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { loading: true };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("setTimeout")
                this.state = { loading: false };
            }, 5000)
        }

        render() {
            console.log("render", this.state.loading)
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} loading={this.state.loading} />;
        }

    }

    WithLoading.displayName = `withLoading(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name})`;

    return WithLoading;

}


function MyComponent({ loading }) {
    console.log("MyComponent loading", loading)
    return (<p>is loading:{loading}</p>)
}


const hoc = withLoading(MyComponent);

export default hoc


Found the problem:
Problem 1: state not changed correctly
 this.setState({ loading: false });

Problem 2:
Inside My component loading prop must use in correct way.
        {loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <p>Hello, world!</p>}



Change this.state = { loading: false } to this.setState({ loading: false }):
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const withLoading = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class WithLoading extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { loading: true };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("setTimeout")
                this.setState({ loading: false });
            }, 5000)
        }

        render() {
            console.log("render", this.state.loading)
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} loading={this.state.loading} />;
        }

    }

    WithLoading.displayName = `withLoading(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name})`;

    return WithLoading;

}


function MyComponent({ loading }) {
    console.log("MyComponent loading", loading)
    return (<p>is loading:{loading}</p>)
}


const hoc = withLoading(MyComponent);

export default hoc

